# Jquery Dialog Pop Up Box Set With PHP Variable Error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I seem to be having an issue with my jquery alert box, I'm trying to trigger them using a number variable called `msg` however I'm setting it using php `$msg` I'm using this to parse the variable over `var msg = '<?php echo $msg ?>';` which I thought was the conventional way. However when I run it won't load and outputs the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Now I know its `var msg = '<?php echo $msg ?>';` causing the problem as if I changed it to `var msg = '1';` it loaded my first alert box.

If anyone knows how I can resolve this that would be great!

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>

    var msg = '<?php echo $msg ?>';

    $( function() {

        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({

            autoOpen: false,

            show: {

                effect: "puff",

                duration: 300

            },

            hide: {

                effect: "clip",

                duration: 500

            }

        });

        if(msg == 1){

            $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );

        }

        $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {

            $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );

        });

    }); 

    $( function() {

        $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({

            autoOpen: false,

            show: {

                effect: "puff",

                duration: 300

            },

            hide: {

                effect: "clip",

                duration: 500

            }

        });

        if(msg == 2){

            $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );

        }

        $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {

            $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );

        });

    });       

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $msg = 1;

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="dialog1" title="Title!">

            <p>This is dialog box number 1.</p>

        </div>

        <div id="dialog2" title="Title!">

            <p>This is dialog box number 1.</p>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a semicolon after $msg; in your php.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but unfortunately a `;` after `$msg` didn't work.

Comment: You can try also <?=$msg;?>

Comment: hmm, try removing the single quotes around <?php echo $msg; ?> - putting those single quotes is making it a string, but you want it to be an integer in javascript when you are doing the comparison..

Comment: @Robbiegod That's got it!

Comment: Thank you, if you post that as the answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: awesome! glad i could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, try removing the single quotes around `<?php echo $msg; ?>` putting those single quotes is making it a string, but you want it to be an integer in JavaScript when you are doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This error you are getting is due to php code placed after js, for sure.

Their are 3 ways to do so -

> 1. Place js code at the end of file.

If you don't get the first way just check out second way

> 2. Alter your js code in this way -

```
var msg = <?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : '2' ?>;
```

Now here you have to pass some default value in our case we passed 2 if `$msg` is not set.

But if your value is dyanamic then i recommend you to go with third way, it will work under every circumstances-

> 3. echo js from php code itself to avoid such syntax error. i.e.

```
<?php
    $msg = 1;
    echo "<script>var msg = $msg</script>";
?>
```

All 3 ways will surely work for you but i recommend you to follow third approach.

Hope you get this right :)